# Is there a addon module to view project phases and tasks?

Tags: odoo

I am using the project module and I want a below view of phase and tasks. This will help me see give an oveall view of where we stand. Is there a module/view which does this ? The current ones seems limited.

[image: image of the view]

[Image http://imagebin.org/index.php?mode=image&id=214416](http://imagebin.org/index.php?mode=image&id=214416)

Cheers,
vishal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module `project_long_term` looks very close to what you need: it adds "phases" to group project tasks. I found a view to display a project + phase gantt chart.

[image]

You can change the Tasks gantt view to display phase + task:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gantt date_start="date_start" 
       date_stop="date_end" 
       string="Tasks" 
       default_group_by="phase_id">
</gantt>
```

The easiest way to do it is:

- activate the developer mode (top right, next to Logout, click on "About" icon and then "Activate the developer mode")
- select Project Tasks from the menu
- next to the title "Search: Tasks" select "Edit GanttView" from the drop-down selection box
- replace the content of the "Architecture" field, save, *et violá*

Note that Tasks may be omitted from the chart if date fields are missing.

Comment: yes I found this module too but I have tired to get a view to display phase+task. Pls help this is my main issue to get started

Comment: I did as per your suggestion but the tasks never showed up even before I made the changes. pls see the video http://youtu.be/v0fTKumRKbg

Comment: Switch to Extended mode (in the user Preferences); now you will see an "Extra Info" tab in the Tasks; complete the "Starting date" field, and eventually the "Ending date".

Comment: I was kind of able to get what I wanted but I still need to work on ur suggestion fully as I was having errors. Will revert next week. Have a nice weekend